# Blurry application in Windows 7 aero mode

Tags: windows-7

When I set my Windows 7 in any of the Aero Themes some application (like Chrome, Evernote, VMware Workstation etc.) renders the fonts all blurry.

Anyone experianced this and know of a solution? I can of course put the application in compability mode and force the system to display everthing in Windows 7 Basic mode but that isn't what I want ...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can happen if your DPI setting is higher than 120dpi and application does not support DPI change.

If this is case you can check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" on shortcut's compatibility tab and that should allow application to scale itself. However, if application's author didn't do his job properly, this will also cause elements to partly (or even fully) go outside application's window.

Comment: Exellent! That helped!

Answer (score 1):

For making all applications work in high DPI and aero, change the windows settings as below

Open Personalization by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Personalization.

In the left pane, click Adjust font size (DPI).If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

In the DPI Scaling dialog box, click **Custom DPI**.

Select the Use **Windows XP style DPI scaling check box**, and then click OK.

[See M.S Windows Help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller)